# Is there a way to use ConvertFrom-SecureString and ConvertTo-SecureString with any user?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm using the following to create the password file:

```
$path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop"
$passwd = Read-Host "enter desired password" -AsSecureString
$encpwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $passwd
$encpwd > $path\filename.bin
```

Then calling the file with:

```
# define path to store password and input password 
$path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop"
# get the encrypted password from the path
$encpwd = Get-Content $path\filename.bin
# convert file to secure string 
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $encpwd
# define needed credential 
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'WIN-SERVER\AdminForQB',$passwd
# go to DVD drive launch setup.exe as user with privileges to launch the program with no user input required
Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2017\"
Start-Process PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Cred $cred -ArgumentList .\QBW32PremierAccountant.exe
```

My goal is be able to run QB2017 with admin privs without giving the user admin privs. The issue I am having is that I have to generate the password file on each user or I get the following error if a user trys to use one generated from another user:

```
Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

Is there a way to use this method without generating a key per user?

Comment: SecureString cmlets use Windows’ Data Protection API when they convert your SecureString to and from a plain text representation. The encryption key is based on your Windows logon credentials so only you can decrypt the data that you’ve encrypted.

Comment: There's a workaround, you can create your secure credentials under their privileges, but it's not hard with know-how to reverse the password `$Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password`

Comment: If you are trying to obfuscate the password making it for them won't cut it since they need to be able to decrypt it which makes the process moot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `ConvertFrom-SecureString` without a `Key` or `SecureKey`, Powershell will use Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) to encrypt/decrypt your strings. This means that it will only work for the same user on the same computer.

When you use a Key/SecureKey, the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm is used. You are able to use the stored credential from any machine with any user so long as you know the AES Key that was used.

[More info on this topic (with example code)](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/)

*Note: This is only Security through obscurity, which isn't good practice. If you store the Key on the same computer as the encrypted password, it's not much more secure than plain text passwords!*

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is the wrong solution for this.

To fix this you should give them read/write access to the folders and registry key QB2017 needs access to. If you still have issues, create a Shim using Microsoft's Application Compatibly Toolkit.

https://deployhappiness.com/fixing-applications-that-require-administrator-rights/